# Prepend timestamp to each line received from stdin

Tags: bash, timestamp, stdin

Hi there I'm trying to create logs using bash but the time I'm getting is wrong. I'm running this in background.

```
# log code here before executing curl script log "Yay I was started"

curl https://example.com/process | sed "s/^/$(date -u) /" >> /path/to/logs.log &
```

The time set after processing curl is the time it was executed not the time after I got the response. I need to get the time after the response.

Here's the sample output (Wrong response)

```
Fri Aug 21 01:43:12 UTC 2020 Yay I was started
Fri Aug 21 01:43:12 UTC 2020 Yay I was the response returned by the url
```

The url here `https://example.com/process` sleeps for 2 seconds but as you can see the time is the same for when it was executed and after it we got the response.

Correct Response

```
Fri Aug 21 01:43:12 UTC 2020 Yay I was started
Fri Aug 21 01:43:14 UTC 2020 Yay I was the response returned by the url
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is because `sed "s/^/$(date -u) /"` captures the date string at the time it is launched and places it at the start of each line. The date string is not updated for each incoming new line from the `curl`'s response.

It is safer to use `awk` rather than `sed`, to prepend the date to each line, as it will capture a new date for each line.

Your original date format is locale formatted, local time. It has been kept here as-is, if it is your preference; but usually logs timestamps are better printed with the [iso.org: ISO 8601 format](https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html), or an UTC relative Unix timestamp.

```sh
curl https://example.com/process |
  awk '{ printf("%s %s\n", strftime("%c", systime()), $0) }' >>/path/to/logs.log &
```

With an ISO-8601 timestamp:

```sh
curl https://example.com/process |
  awk '{ printf("%s %s\n", strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z", systime()), $0) }' \
    >>/path/to/logs.log &
```

See `man strftime` for time formatting.

Comment: This is wonderful. I'll accept this as the answer but I'll have a follow up question. What If i needed only 1 date/time per response of the url not per line is that possible? Thanks.

Comment: @Defyleiti to have only one timestamp prepend per `curl` request: `curl https://example.com/process | { printf '%s ' "$(date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z)"; cat; }` or with bash's built-in `printf`: `curl https://example.com/process | { printf '%(%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z)T '; cat; }`