# Timestamp variable in my Bash Shell Script is not changing in log file

Tags: bash, shell, logging, timestamp

I have a shell script that calls 2 other scripts that take many positional parameters.

> **Main Script**

```
LOGFILE="status.log"
TIMESTAMP="`date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"` $BASH_SOURCE : "

sudo ./call_script_A arg1 arg2 
echo "$TIMESTAMP task 1 complete" | tee -a $LOGFILE

sudo ./call_script_B arg1 arg2 arg3 
echo "$TIMESTAMP task 2 complete" | tee -a $LOGFILE

.
.
.
sudo ./call_script_A arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4
echo "$TIMESTAMP task n complete" | tee -a $LOGFILE
```

> **And the output log from the above script after several hours was:**

```
2020-08-28 09:44:43 ./main_script.sh : task 1 complete 
2020-08-28 09:44:43 ./main_script.sh : task 2 complete 
2020-08-28 09:44:43 ./main_script.sh : task 3 complete 
2020-08-28 09:44:43 ./main_script.sh : task 4 complete 
2020-08-28 09:44:43 ./main_script.sh : task 5 complete 
2020-08-28 09:44:43 ./main_script.sh : task n complete
```

> **Notice how the timestamps stay constant despite the fact that its been echo'd several times in the main script above?**

On all my scripts, i have the below 2 lines.

```
LOGFILE="status.log"
TIMESTAMP="`date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"` $BASH_SOURCE : "
```

How do I debug this situation considering the fact that I am using these variables across all my scripts?

Comment: Update variable TIMESTAMP before printing it.

Comment: But the back tick around `date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"` in TIMESTAMP variable should evaluate at every echo call right which is correctly working on other scripts?

Comment: No bash evaluates this only once in your line with `TIMESTAMP=`.

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prepend timestamp to each line received from stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63559785/prepend-timestamp-to-each-line-received-from-stdin)

Comment: @daylightsaving Variables contain static data, not procedures for generating data. The value of a variable doesn't change unless you do something to update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subshell evaluates before assigning the variable. What you want is a *function*.

```
$: logfile="status.log"

$: Log() {
    echo "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') $BASH_SOURCE : $@" | tee -a $logfile
   }

$: Log task     1        complete 
2020-08-28 13:44:58 main : task 1 complete

$: cat status.log
2020-08-28 13:44:58 main : task 1 complete

$:     Log "task 2 complete"
2020-08-28 13:45:26 main : task 2 complete

$: cat status.log
2020-08-28 13:44:58 main : task 1 complete
2020-08-28 13:45:26 main : task 2 complete

$:     Log "task      3       complete"
2020-08-28 13:49:28 main : task      3       complete

$: cat status.log
2020-08-28 13:44:58 main : task 1 complete
2020-08-28 13:45:26 main : task 2 complete
2020-08-28 13:49:28 main : task      3       complete
```